# Issues creating / setting up Laravel Project (Laravel Newbie)

Tags: php, laravel

I've started playing around with Laravel and have run into problems almost immediately and wondered if anyone had the same issues.

I've installed composer and tried setting up a new laravel project using

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

It looks like it starts to work then when I get to "Installing dependencies, Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.1)" it quits with an error saying segmentation fault.

I subsequently downloaded a laravel base project from the laravel git hub and tried installing with `composer install` but got the same issue.

Lastly i tried installing composer directly to the project directory using the curl command `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` and then using the command `php compser.phar install` but again with the same issue.

Not sure where to go next so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's probably not a composer or laravel issue, I think the issue is in your PHP installation. If you can, try to reinstall PHP.

Comment: I am using the php installation that comes with MAMP for Windows, I did wonder if that may be the cause. Is it best to use a standalone version of PHP with Laravel? I've never installed it outside of an Apache / MySQL, PHP stack before.

Comment: Are you using linux? What does `which composer` give? or `php --version`

Comment: Ahh windows :( Did you try installing composer via the `Composer-Setup.exe`. https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: No, on Windows (unfortunately) 

Which Composer = /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer PHP Version = PHP 5.6.8 (cli) (built: May 13 2015 22:19:06) 

Yeah, I used Composer-Setup.exe originally to install

Comment: Check if the required extensions of php are enabled. Go to your `php.ini` and find `extension=php_mbstring.dll`, `extension=php_openssl.dll` and make sure they are not preceded by `;` which comments them out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was issues with the proxy server at work in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try install Via Laravel Installer

```
composer global remove laravel/installer

composer global require laravel/installer
```

After laravel istaller install

```
laravel new project_name
```